# Running php Doctrine commands via bash script

Tags: php, bash, symfony, scripting, doctrine

I'm currently developing a PHP application using Symfony and Doctrine. My goal at this point is to create a bash script to build my database schema and load fixtures. My current script lives in the /bin folder and has the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate
```

The script is executable and when I try to run it (`./create_de.sh`), I get the following error:

```
Could not open input file: bin/console
```

I tried to change the script to be the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

php console doctrine:migrations:migrate
php console doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate
```

But I still get the same error, except without the bin part.

When I run the commands in the script via command line I have no problems. Any idea why this script doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Since the script lives inside the bin folder, just change it to:

```
php ./console doctrine:migrations:migrate
php ./console doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate
```

Edit: there isn't any permissions issue here as other comments suggest, as the permissions of the console file are by default `-rwxr-xr-x` which means everyone can execute it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried (from within `bin/`) `dos2unix create_de.sh > create_de_new.sh`, then `./create_de_new.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your permissions, the file bin/console must to have execution permissions:

Something like:

```
chmod +x bin/console
```